# Injecting elements to an existing list in Spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

#### Description

The general use case scenario is - in the world of application package dependency graph, we want to have a collection in parent package and we want to make it available for all children packages to add elements to the list, in other words, extending the list for higher level execution in the parent package.

The goal is let downstream applications able to inject elements to this higher level applications predefined collection so that we achieve federated model for elements while keeping  overall execution control in the parent application package.

#### Example

Say we have 2 application packages
- parent package
- child/children package(s)

The children packages child listed parent package as build dependency

In parent package's spring configuration xml, we have a list that need to be injected with instances of a class really.fun.processor

```
<util:list id="myProcessors" value-type="really.fun.processor" />
```

If we host the classes and their instances (beans) in the child package (such as below beans), is it possible to inject back to the parent's list?

```
<bean name="funProcessor1" class="really.fun.processor"/>
<bean name="funProcessor2" class="really.fun.processor"/>
...
<bean name="funProcessorN" class="really.fun.processor"/>
```

#### Question

Is this possible in Spring? If so, what's recommended approaches for this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution:

1. ComponentScan https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html
2. EnableAutoConfiguration https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.8.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html

Both are designed to solve the above use case very nicely.